# Javascript selected text highlighting prob

Tags: javascript, getselection

I have a html page with text content. On selecting any text and pressing the highlight button, I can change the style of the selected text to highlight the same. To implement this feature, i have written the following method.

```
sel = window.getSelection();
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = "highlight" + color;
range.surroundContents(span);
```

This is working fine if you choose a text with no html tag, but when the text has any html tag in between, it is giving error

> Failed to execute 'surroundContents' on 'Range': The Range has partially selected a non-Text node.

How to solve this problem. Is it possible to highlight the same separately for each part(divided by html tags)?

Comment: That is going to be difficult. If you think about it, you couldn't end up with something like `<div>unselected here<span>selected</div><div>selected here</span> more unselected at the end</div>` because that would break the DOM tree. You'd need to put a span into the text at the base node, then at the target node. Also any nodes in between if you wanted those too but I'm not sure those are accessible through the selection APIs

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
if (window.getSelection) {
                var sel = window.getSelection();
                if (!sel) {
                    return;
                }
                var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                var start = range.startContainer;
                var end = range.endContainer;
                var commonAncestor = range.commonAncestorContainer;
                var nodes = [];
                var node;

                for (node = start.parentNode; node; node = node.parentNode){
                   var tempStr=node.nodeValue;
                   if(node.nodeValue!=null &&    tempStr.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'')!='')
                     nodes.push(node);
                   if (node == commonAncestor)
                     break;
                }
                nodes.reverse();

                for (node = start; node; node = getNextNode(node)){
                   var tempStr=node.nodeValue;
                   if(node.nodeValue!=null &&  tempStr.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'')!='')
                     nodes.push(node);
                   if (node == end)
                    break;
                }

                for(var i=0 ; i<nodes.length ; i++){

                   var sp1 = document.createElement("span");
                   sp1.setAttribute("class", "highlight"+color );
                   var sp1_content = document.createTextNode(nodes[i].nodeValue);
                   sp1.appendChild(sp1_content);
                   var parentNode = nodes[i].parentNode;
                   parentNode.replaceChild(sp1, nodes[i]);
                }
           }
```

Answer (score 38):

See [`Range.extractContents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range/extractContents):

```js
document.getElementById('execute').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
        span = document.createElement('span');

    span.className = 'highlight';
    span.appendChild(range.extractContents());
    range.insertNode(span);
});
```

```css
.highlight { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div id="test">
    Select any part of <b>this text and</b> then click 'Run'.
</div>

<button id="execute">Run</button>
```

Comment: Put a sibling in there though instead of a child and it breaks: http://jsfiddle.net/sL7joxhs/ - Highlight some text from `test1` and `test2` and it wraps both divs in a span and breaks structure

Comment: Yes, span.appendChild(range.extractContents()) is breaking the paragraph if the selected text are in more than one para. How to solve this issue?

Comment: @RGraham @dev_android It's only "broken" from a visual sense—inspect the markup and verify for yourself that the DOM structure is valid. It *looks* wrong because of the mixture of block and inline elements (i.e., `div` and `span`)—the Range API is not to blame there. [Replace the `div`s with `span`s and you'll see that nothing looks broken](http://jsfiddle.net/sL7joxhs/1/).

Comment: @AndréDion See it's not just a HTML validity problem here, it's actually changed the structure of the tree. Where once you had `<span>asd</span><span>asd</span>` which you would expect to turn into: `<span>as<span class="highlight">d</span></span><span><span class="highlight">a</span>sd</span>` to keep structure, you've now got `<span>as</span><span class="highlight"><span>d</span><span>....` and so on, which would break any queries you've been running based on that structure. Hope that makes sense. Difficult to explain in a comment!

Comment: @RGraham This discussion is starting to veer away from the context of the question as it was originally asked (which was really about the exception OP was seeing) but why would you expect to see two new nodes given one DOM extraction and subsequent insert?

Comment: It is not possible to replace DIVs with span in all cases. Moreover it may be not only DIV, may be <P>, <H1>,<H2> and many other. What is the generic way out for this problem?

Comment: @dev_android The solution I've given presents a technique, not a be-all, end-all solution. You need to apply that for your given use-case, which you have't really explained to begin with. The question you originally asked ("Why am I getting this exception?") has been answered. Open a new question for a different problem.

Comment: The actual question was - "How to solve this problem. Is it possible to highlight the same separately for each part(divided by html tags)?"

Answer (score 6):

Rather than reinvent the wheel, I'd use [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy)'s highlighting capabilities.

I've forked the fiddle that [RGraham created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894781/javascript-selected-text-highlighting-prob#comment47913358_29895300) and created a [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsp04pd3/) that shows how it works. This is how it is done:

```
var applier = rangy.createClassApplier("highlight");
var highlighter = rangy.createHighlighter();
highlighter.addClassApplier(applier);

document.getElementById('execute').addEventListener('click', function() {
    highlighter.removeAllHighlights();
    highlighter.highlightSelection("highlight");
});
```

What this does is create a highlighter that will set the `highlight` class on elements that are wholly inside the selection, and create spans with the `highlight` class as needed for elements that straddle the selection. When the button with the id `execute` is clicked, the old highlights are removed and the new highlights applied.

The highlighter functionality is part of release of Rangy that are considered to be "alpha". **However,** I've been consistently using alpha releases of Rangy for a few years now but it has been *extremely* rare that I found a problem with my application that I could trace back to Rangy. And the few times I found a problem with Rangy, Tim Down (its author) was quite responsive.

Comment: 1. can one use rangy to highlight / unhighlight an existing range (not a selection)? 2. if yes, will it do that in an idempotent manner (no side effects. IOW, does it leave the dom as it found it before that pair of operations)?

Answer (score 5):

My solution highlighting all selected nodes.

```
function highlight() {
  const sel = window.getSelection();
  const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  const {
    commonAncestorContainer,
    startContainer,
    endContainer,
    startOffset,
    endOffset,
  } = range;
  const nodes = [];

  console.group("range");

  console.log("range", range);
  console.log("commonAncestorContainer", commonAncestorContainer);
  console.log("startContainer", startContainer);
  console.log("endContainer", endContainer);
  console.log("startOffset", startOffset);
  console.log("endOffset", endOffset);
  console.log("startContainer.parentNode", startContainer.parentNode);
  console.groupEnd();

  if (startContainer === endContainer) {
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = "highlight";
    range.surroundContents(span);
    return;
  }

  // get all posibles selected nodes
  function getNodes(childList) {
    console.group("***** getNode: ", childList);
    childList.forEach((node) => {
      console.log("node:", node, "nodoType", node.nodeType);

      const nodeSel = sel.containsNode(node, true);
      console.log("nodeSel", nodeSel);

      // if is not selected
      if (!nodeSel) return;

      const tempStr = node.nodeValue;
      console.log("nodeValue:", tempStr);

      if (node.nodeType === 3 && tempStr.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, "") !== "") {
        console.log("nodo agregado");
        nodes.push(node);
      }

      if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        if (node.childNodes) getNodes(node.childNodes);
      }
    });
    console.groupEnd();
  }

  getNodes(commonAncestorContainer.childNodes);

  console.log(nodes);

  nodes.forEach((node, index, listObj) => {
    const { nodeValue } = node;
    let text, prevText, nextText;

    if (index === 0) {
      prevText = nodeValue.substring(0, startOffset);
      text = nodeValue.substring(startOffset);
    } else if (index === listObj.length - 1) {
      text = nodeValue.substring(0, endOffset);
      nextText = nodeValue.substring(endOffset);
    } else {
      text = nodeValue;
    }

    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = "highlight";
    span.append(document.createTextNode(text));
    const { parentNode } = node;

    parentNode.replaceChild(span, node);

    if (prevText) {
      const prevDOM = document.createTextNode(prevText);
      parentNode.insertBefore(prevDOM, span);
    }

    if (nextText) {
      const nextDOM = document.createTextNode(nextText);
      parentNode.insertBefore(nextDOM, span.nextSibling);
    }
  });

  sel.removeRange(range);
}
```

Example https://codesandbox.io/s/api-selection-multiple-with-nodes-gx2is?file=/index.html

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Comment: Is there a way to unhighlight the text too?

Comment: @ryan yes is similar, instead of inserting an <span/> you can get it first and the delete it.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

This solution is bit tricky, but I find it would be sufficient

When you will see closely in selection object that we get through  calling

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
```

You will se that there are 4 properties: `startContainer`, `startOffset`, `endContainer`, `endOffset`.

So now you need to start with `startContainer` with `startOffset` and start putting your necessary span nodes from there.

If now it `endContainer` is different node then you need to start traversing nodes from `startContainer` to `endContainer`

For traversing you need to check for child nodes and sibling nodes which you can get from DOM objects. So first go through `startContainer`, go through all its child and check if child node is inline element then apply span tag around it, and then you need to write few coding for various corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
newNode.appendChild(range.extractContents())
```

according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range/extractContents):

> Partially selected nodes are cloned to include the parent tags
>   necessary to make the document fragment valid.

Whereas [Range.surroundContents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range/surroundContents):

> An exception will be thrown, however, if the Range splits a non-Text
>   node with only one of its boundary points. That is, unlike the
>   alternative above, if there are partially selected nodes, they will
>   not be cloned and instead the operation will fail.

Didn't test, but...

Answer (score -2):

The solution is really tricky.
I somehow find a workaround. See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xalvin11/z34akp6q/)

```
function highlight() {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
        parent = range.commonAncestorContainer,
        start = range.startContainer,
        end = range.endContainer;
    var startDOM = (start.parentElement == parent) ? start.nextSibling : start.parentElement;
    var currentDOM = startDOM.nextElementSibling;
    var endDOM = (end.parentElement == parent) ? end : end.parentElement;
    //Process Start Element
    highlightText(startDOM, 'START', range.startOffset);
    while (currentDOM != endDOM && currentDOM != null) {
        highlightText(currentDOM);
        currentDOM = currentDOM.nextElementSibling;
    }
    //Process End Element
    highlightText(endDOM, 'END', range.endOffset);
}

function highlightText(elem, offsetType, idx) {
    if (elem.nodeType == 3) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.setAttribute('class', 'highlight');
        var origText = elem.textContent, text, prevText, nextText;
        if (offsetType == 'START') {
            text = origText.substring(idx);
            prevText = origText.substring(0, idx);
        } else if (offsetType == 'END') {
            text = origText.substring(0, idx);
            nextText = origText.substring(idx);
        } else {
            text = origText;
        }
        span.textContent = text;

        var parent = elem.parentElement;
        parent.replaceChild(span, elem);
        if (prevText) { 
            var prevDOM = document.createTextNode(prevText);
            parent.insertBefore(prevDOM, span);
        }
        if (nextText) {
            var nextDOM = document.createTextNode(nextText);
            parent.appendChild(nextDOM);
        }
        return;
    }
    var childCount = elem.childNodes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        if (offsetType == 'START' && i == 0) 
            highlightText(elem.childNodes[i], 'START', idx);
        else if (offsetType == 'END' && i == childCount - 1)
            highlightText(elem.childNodes[i], 'END', idx);
        else
            highlightText(elem.childNodes[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for real web pages http://jsfiddle.net/0c67pqrt/ select quite a bit of text in middle of paragraph and see.